# .Net dll function returns just first char of string in Python

Tags: python, .net, string, dll, ctypes

I want to call **.NET** dll in my python project. I want to use a function which returns string and gets string parameter. But somehow I cant get the string I can just get the first char of the string and sometimes it raises **following error:**

```
'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 1-15: character maps to     <undefined>
```

**EDIT**: Solved the error by putting some piece of code.

```
encode(sys.stdout.encoding, errors='replace')
```

But this time result is not exactly what I want. Result is : **b'h\xe7\x8c\x80'** with the input **"hello"**

Here is my code:

```
import ctypes
import time

hllDll = ctypes.WinDLL ("C:\\Users\\yazilimhpaio2\\Downloads\\mydll.dll")


hllApiProto = ctypes.WINFUNCTYPE (
    ctypes.c_wchar_p,    # Return type.
    ctypes.c_wchar_p     # Parameter 1 ...
)                 

hllApiParams = (1,"p1",0),

hllApi = hllApiProto (("ReturnMyString", hllDll), hllApiParams)

var = "hello"

p1 = ctypes.c_wchar_p (var)

x = hllApi (p1)

print(x.encode(sys.stdout.encoding, errors='replace'))

time.sleep(3)
```

**ReturnMyString** function gets string parameter and returns that parameter. But when I run this code it just prints first letter of my parameter.

I found out that [c_wchar_p is used for string](https://docs.python.org/3.1/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types) in python.
So I couldn't understand what is the problem with my code.

Any help would be appreciated..

**EDIT:**

**exported dll function:**

```
[ComVisible(true)]
[DllExport("ReturnMyString", CallingConvention = System.Runtime.InteropServices.CallingConvention.StdCall)]
public static string ReturnMyString(string value)
{
    return value;
}
```

**Prototype:**

```
public static string ReturnMyString(string)
```

Comment: What is the prototype of the C function you are trying to call?  If it takes `char*`, use `c_char_p`, if it takes `wchar_t*` use `c_wchar_p`.  I suspect it is the former.  If so don't pass a Python 3 string, but use a byte string...`b'hello'` for example.

Comment: @MarkTolonen The dll is written in C# so it takes only string and returns string.

Comment: Then show how you export the DLL function. Show the prototype. You still have to export a C prototype to call it from `ctypes`. If you are only seeing the first character it implies `c_char_p` should be used, because `c_wchar_p` will pass the string as `'h\x00e\x00l\x00l\x00o\x00'` and look null terminated after the first byte.

Comment: You can see edited post. But there is no char* or something I don't know what to do.

Comment: Are you using [Unmanaged Exports](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports)?  It's [Marshaling Example](https://sites.google.com/site/robertgiesecke/Home/uploads/unmanagedexports#TOC-Marshalling-sample) says ".Net will marshal these strings as single-byte Ansi" by default.  If so, use `c_char_p` and pass byte strings from Python.

Comment: Yes that worked! You really saved my days! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Cool! I'll add that comment as an answer then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you using Unmanaged Exports its Marshaling Example says ".Net will marshal these strings as single-byte Ansi" by default. If so, use c_char_p and pass byte strings from Python.